# VSTO project is it possible to add colors and items from windows forms

Tags: winforms, vsto, office-interop

In VSTO, I'm using VS 2012 with Excel 2013, and the Ribbon area I create with an addin looks so plain vanilla ( font is not able to be in bold etc..)  It would be great to extend the look and feel and functionality of this along with tying in Event handlers for status updates.

Does anyone have any experience with extending VSTO,  any samples, links that you found very useful ( yes I spent a lot of time on google already.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style of the Ribbon is controlled by Office. 
There is not anything you can do to change the format and styling of the fonts. The options you do have are size of the controls (e.g. buttons) & their icons.

It's also possible to use Office events to update the appearance of the ribbon.
If you have a specific scenario in mind, I'd be happy to help. 
In the meantime, here are some helpful links:

[Ribbon Extensibility Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[How to: Customize the Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942954%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[VSTO - Create a custom tab for the Office Ribbon in Excel (Visual Studio 2012)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VSTO-Create-a-custom-tab-5d7d5198)